# macOS - Unable to create provisioning profile to distribute outside the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, networkextension

I have a Mac App that uses NetworkExtention, and I'm trying to distribute it outside the AppStore.
I'm following the [steps](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev033e997ca) that Apple mentioned on their website.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to create a provisioning profile from both Xcode & Apple Developer account...

I'm getting the following error in Xcode:

> Provisioning profile "Mac Team Provisioning Profile: com.app.****" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension entitlement.

I'm getting this error because I changed the values of the **.entitlements** file as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_networking_networkextension) to

```
<key>com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension</key>
<array>
    <string>app-proxy-provider-systemextension</string>
    <string>content-filter-provider-systemextension</string>
    <string>packet-tunnel-provider-systemextension</string>
</array>
```

If I try to create the provisioning profile through the Apple Developer Account, I'm Always getting this, even though I had created a certificate for a Developer ID
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following this question

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same issue and this was able to fix the error by contacting the Apple admin.

Failure to create a provisioning profile using Developer ID when there is an actual certificate is an Apple problem, and the problem has been resolved in Apple Korea.

I hope this reply was helpful.